# why is Cin.getline(); ending my connection to my socket? (networking) (socket programming)

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, winsock

Before I start I want to clarify that I'm using the socket code from microsoft as a template.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-client-code

I want to talk to a server to play a game over a set of moves but whenever I use std::cin.getline(); the while loop stops and the socket closes. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Here is a snippet of my code:
.
.
.

```
    const char *sendbuf = "NEWG";
    // comment this when testing cin.
    char recvbuf[DEFAULT_BUFLEN];
    int recvbuflen = DEFAULT_BUFLEN;
    
    // Receive until the peer closes the connection
    //  we need to communicate to the server 

    printf(" | | | \\    / _  |  _  _  ._ _   _  | | |\n");
    printf(" o o o  \\/\\/ (/_ | (_ (_) | | | (/_ o o o\n");
    char *usrin;
    std::cout << "Welcome to the tictactoe game !!\n";
    int x = 1;
while (true) {
    std::cout <<"test";
    //std::cin.getline(sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf));
    // if(sendbuf == 0){
    //     std::cout << "give me sometthign to work with!";
    // } 
    std::cout << "test";
    // Send user input to the server
    int iResult = send(ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("send failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Bytes Sent: %d\n", iResult);

    // Receive and print data from the server
    iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
    if (iResult > 0) {
        printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        recvbuf[iResult] = '\0'; // Null-terminate the received data
        printf("Received data: %s\n", recvbuf);
    } else if (iResult == 0) {
        printf("Connection closed\n");
    } else {
        printf("recv failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    }
    
}

    // cleanup
    closesocket(ConnectSocket);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

.
.
.

Any help would be great thank you very much I am so lost
.

I tried changing the variable type from 'const char *' to simply 'char', and then 'char *.'
It gave me an error..

I tried using'>>' instead of getline().
the same thing happened

I tried getting another value from anoutehr variable I initialized in the terminal.
This didn't work because the issue was from the function 'cin'.

Comment: Which textbook or a reputable study guide are you working with, to learn how to correctly use sockets? The shown code exhibits multiple fundamental flaws with how sockets should be used, namely a complete lack of proper handling of `send` and `recv`. Furthermore, `std::cin.getline(sendbuf, strlen(sendbuf));` does not do what you think it does, either. That, combined with an odd mixture of using both `printf` and `cout`, strongly suggests that a search engine was used as a replacement for a good textbook. Sorry, this is too complex to be learned from search engine results, you need a textbook.

Comment: I really didn't use a textbook or anything. We had 3 normal simple readings for sockets in python though. most of the code was from  the microsoft website listed above.

Comment: I didn't want to handle send and recv until I knew that the process worked and I prefer using cout and cin over printf.

Comment: Honestly, this is all self-taught through youtube sorry If it looks like I am using AI; Im not

Comment: See, that's the problem. Do you understand what each one of the parameters to all these functions call do? Why does your call to `getline` pass `strlen(sendbuf)` for the second parameter, what does that mean? What led you to conclude that this is how to correctly use `getline`, here? Because this looks similar to other nearby code? Sorry, this just won't work, and will always result in endless tears and frustrations.

Comment: Finally, it is true that Microsoft's sample code uses `send`/`recv` in somewhat similar fashion. But that code example is just intended to be a rough, simplistic, bare bones, code example. This is not how professional, quality C++ code should work. If someone's job was to write reliable, bullet-proof C++ code, and they wrote code like that, that failed to check `recv`/`send`'s return value, and properly handle partial read/writes, they'll lose their jobs.

Comment: @FardinMahid - The problem isn't your google search, but that people knowing less than you post "tutorials" and videos on internet. And if you cannot tell the good from the bad, how are they going to help you? (And if you know, you don't need them. Catch-22 :-)

Comment: Google search is not a replacement for a C++ textbook. Stackoverflow [maintains a list of recommended C++ textbooks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 0):

In your commented code, you are having `std::cin.getline()` read into the memory that `sendbuf` is pointing at.  The problem is, `sendbuf` is pointing at a *string literal*, which is **read-only** memory.  Thus your code invokes *undefined behavior* that is likely causing an Access Violation at runtime which kills your process.

You need to have `getline()` read into **writable** memory instead, such as your `recvbuf` array.